# Video not shown in ported blackberry 10 from android

Tags: android, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

I have ported my android application to blackberry 10 using **The blackberry runtime for android apps** .  My android app is ported fine and its running on blackberry 10 simulator.

I have a video to be played at the very first install of my app. This video is played well in android. But in my ported blackberry app the video is not at all shown.Instead I get a blank screen being displayed for few seconds and the application starts as usual from the home screen.

I am using **Video View ** in android. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you see any errors?

Comment: No. I don't get any errors.